# in foreach, isLastItem() exists?

Tags: php, foreach

Using a regular for loop, it's possible to comapred the current index with the last to tell if I'm in the last iteration of the loop. Is there a similar thing when using `foreach`? I mean something like this.

```
foreach($array as $item){
  //do stuff
  //then check if we're in the last iteration of the loop
  $last_iteration = islast(); //boolean true/false
}
```

If not, is there at least a way to know the current index of the current iteration like `$iteration = 5`, so I can manually compare it to the length of the `$array`?

Comment: Sadly, there is no such function, at least not in native PHP. I wonder whether it's possible by querying the current pointer position within the array? Have never seen anything like it, though, so probably not.

Comment: Maybe you should elaborate on why you would want to know if the current value is the last value.

Comment: So is there at least a way to know the current index of the current iteration like `$iteration = 5`, so I can manually compare it to the length of the `$array`?

Comment: @Gumbo I need to take specific action (or not take specific action), like NOT adding bottom border markup to the markup of a table. That sort of thing..

Comment: @zmol: You can handle that with CSS.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use a combination of [SPL](http://php.net/book.spl)’s [*ArrayIterator*](http://php.net/class.arrayiterator) and [*CachingIterator* class](http://php.net/class.cachingiterator) to have a [`hasNext` method](http://php.net/cachingiterator.hasnext):

```
$iter = new CachingIterator(new ArrayIterator($arr));
foreach ($iter as $value) {
    $last_iteration = !$iter->hasNext();
}
```

Answer (score 22):

The counter method is probably the easiest.

```
$i = count($array);
foreach($array as $item){
  //do stuff
  //then check if we're in the last iteration of the loop
  $last_iteration = !(--$i); //boolean true/false
}
```

Comment: +1 I up voted Gumbo but your solution does seem to do the same and is a lot simpler

Answer (score 2):

Here are a few methods for this;

```
$items  = ["Bhir", "Ekky", null, "Uych", "foo"=>"bar"];
$values = array_values($items);

// Bhir, Ekky, Uych, bar
foreach ($values as $i => $item) {
    print("$item");
    $next = isset($values[$i + 1]);
    if ($next) {
        print(", ");
    }
}

// Bhir, Ekky, , Uych, bar
foreach ($values as $i => $item) {
    print("$item");
    $next = array_key_exists($i + 1, $values);
    if ($next) {
        print(", ");
    }
}

// Bhir, Ekky, , Uych, bar
$i = count($values);
foreach ($items as $item) {
    print("$item");
    $next = !!(--$i);
    if ($next) {
        print(", ");
    }
}

// Bhir, Ekky, , Uych, bar
$items = new \CachingIterator(new \ArrayIterator($items));
foreach ($items as $item) {
    print("$item");
    $next = $items->hasNext();
    if ($next) {
        print(", ");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

No, you need to have a counter and know the amount of items in the list. You can use [`end()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.end.php) to get the last item in an array and see if it matches the current value in your `foreach`.

Comment: Good workaround, but as @Dan Grossman's points out, this depends on the values being unique so that there's no mixup.

Answer (score 1):

If you know that the values of the array will always be unique, you can compare the current `$item` to `end($array)` to know if you're at the last item yet. Otherwise, no, you need a counter.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the key and the value in `foreach()` like this:

`foreach($array as $key=>$value) { ... }`

Alternatively, you could do a `count()` of the array so you know how many items there are and have an incrementing counter so that you know when you've reached the last item.

Answer (score 1):

```
end($array);
$lastKey = key($array);
foreach($array as $key => $value) {
   if ($key === $lastKey) {
      // do something endish
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The valid() method says if the ArrayIterator object has more elements.

See:

```
$arr = array("Banana","Abacaxi","Abacate","Morango");

$iter = new ArrayIterator($arr);

while($iter->valid()){

    echo $iter->key()." - ".$iter->current()."<br/>";

    $iter->next();

}
```