# easiest way to establish that a foreach loop is in it's final iteration

Tags: php, loops, foreach

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to determine the first and last iteration in a foreach loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1070244/how-to-determine-the-first-and-last-iteration-in-a-foreach-loop)

what is the best way to establish that a foreach loop is in it's final loop, and perform different functions accordingly?

Comment: Duplicate of at least [How to determine the first and last iteration in a foreach loop?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1070244), [in foreach, isLastItem() exists?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4943719), [How do you find the last element of an array while iterating using a foreach loop in php ?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/665135) and [probably a lot more](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bphp%5D+foreach+last).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The way I would approach this is to increment a variable and test that variable against the size of the array ([`count()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.count.php)):

```
$i = 0;
$c = count($array);

foreach($array as $key => $value) {
    $i++;
    if ($i == $c) {
        // last iteration
    }
    else {
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

This may, obviously, not be the most efficient method, though.

Comment: and what is a purpose of such stuff, if we already have for cycle?

Comment: @Ashot: the purpose of 'such stuff' is to answer the question as it was asked. I assumed, perhaps unfairly, that the OP knew of, and chose not to use, a `for` loop for a particular reason.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways of doing this:

1. Determine what the last value of the array is before entering the loop, and on each iteration compare the current item to that previously-identified one.
2. Use a `for` loop instead, or an incrementing variable with the foreach loop to check `if(count($someArr) - 1 == $currentIteration)`. If so, do that logic.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO the best way is to use `for` loop for such cases.

Answer (score 0):

hm...
use this:

```
 $i =0;
 $c = count($employeeAges);
    foreach( $employeeAges as $key => $value){
    if($c-$i<=1){
          //DO SOMETHING
        }else{
          //default for other loops
        }
        i++;
     }
```