# Javascript boolean true/false shorthand in jQuery

Tags: jquery

Looking at jQuery's [deferred.js](https://github.com/lydonchandra/jquery/blob/master/src/deferred.js#L109) source code,

```
} else if ( !( --remaining ) ) {
    deferred.resolveWith( contexts, values );
}
```

What does !( --remaining) comparison do ?

From https://stackoverflow.com/a/4943788/115988, it looks like it's a 'confusing' shorthand boolean check?

Answer (score 3):

It is checking that value of `remaining` is not equal to `0` (while also decrementing the value).

Essentially it is doing this:

```
...
else if ( remaining -= 1 && !( remaining ) ) { 
    deferred.resolveWith( contexts, values );
}
```

Comment: No. It decrements `remaining` first, and then tests.

Comment: @dda oops. messed up my post and pre increments :-P

Comment: Don't you just love C-syntax? :-)

Comment: @Neal not using code above, will be using code in my answer below instead.

Comment: @portoalet the code in your original post works perfectly fine! why change it??

Answer (score 0):

`!(--remaining)`:

> ! Not True test
>
> -- decrement

--> decrement remaining and then test whether it's == 0.

Answer (score -1):

Much easier to read version of !(--remaining), 
will need to profile the performance.

```
                } else if( remaining > 0 ) {
                    --remaining;

                    // if --remaining === 0, then resolve Deferred
                    if( remaining === 0 ) {
                        deferred.resolveWith( contexts, values );
                    }
                }
```